# Search XmlNode by attribute

Tags: xmldocument, xmlnode

I have XmlDocument. I don't know XPath, I only know that this xml document has node named "h3" with attribute id="PortalName" and this attribute is unique for all xml document. How to find this node? I try:

```
        XmlNode xnList = doc.SelectSingleNode("h3[@id='PortalName']");
```

but it does not work because it search only in root node. How to search in whole document?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately that's pretty easy:

```
XmlNode xnList = doc.SelectSingleNode("//h3[@id='PortalName']");
```

The "//h3" means "any h3 element in the whole document". (See the [abbreviated syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) in the XPath spec for more information.)